# How to have two CodeMirror editors side by side

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I need to have two [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) editors side by side, but they always show *after* each other.

I tried:

1. Changing the `width` CSS property (of the `textarea` or a parent element, e.g. `span`).
2. Use editor.`setSize('50%', null)`

But couldn't figure it out.

Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ua30wbfb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using float:

```
<span style='float: left;'><textarea id='ta1'>First</textarea></span>
<span><textarea id='ta2'>Second</textarea></span>
```